# Prove geodesics are straight lines if Riemann tensor is identically zero.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, geodesic

Suppose that $R^{a}_{bcd}\equiv 0$ in all of our manifold $M$ (in which we assume zero torsion). Prove that all geodesics are straight lines.

I tried using Ricci's identity: $X^i_{;jk}-X^i_{;kj}=R^i_{mkj}X^m$ but expanding the right side and equating to zero only led me to the expression for $R$ in terms of the connection coefficients $\Gamma$.

I was hinted that I might use the parallel transport property along a circuit or that in a torsionless setting, $\nabla_X\nabla_X Z=R(X,Z,X)=0$. My problem lies in the fact that I don't entirely understand that last equation, and most references on the subject make use of properties of a Riemannian metric on the manifold, concept not yet introduced at this point in my course.

All and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems strange the metric tensor hasn't been introduced to you yet

Comment: Not necessarily: in plane polar coordinates the Christoffels don't vanish, even though the geodesics remain straight lines.
And even if I was working in a coordinate system in which what you said was true, how does one prove that a vanishing Riemann tensor implies vanishing Christoffels? That was my initial line of attack.

Comment: I'm sorry, vanishing of the Riemann tensor only implies that there exists some coordinate system where the connection vanishes

Answer (score 0):

The result is false. A quick class of counterexamples is the following: consider any diffeomorphism $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$. Let $\delta$ be the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^n$. Then the pullback metric $f^*\delta$ is a flat metric on $\mathbb R^n$ in which the geodesics typically aren't straight lines.

I realize that this answer perhaps contains technical language that you haven't yet seen, but you will learn about metrics and pullback soon in your class (I hope!). Furthermore, the above paragraph is a point that seems to be missed by a lot of students, so keep it in mind for the future
:-)

Comment: Pullbacks and pushforwards are not a problem. At this point we we're discussing the metric-independent geometry of spaces so metrics are not used up to this point (and in the desired problem).
On whether or not this result is false, several books (among which is Schutz's Geometrical Methods of Math. Phys., see section 6.10) state that a space is flat if and only if the Riemann tensor is identically zero, though there might be some unsaid assumptions, and they use a variant of the geodesic deviation equation to "prove it".